# How to arrange a data table by input column name in Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to code an app for my data visualization project due in a week, but I can't seem to get my app to give the output I want. The app is supposed to take some inputs (a person's education [this has no effect on the output] and three skills they posses), and arrange the given data table so that the resulting arranged table has the best matched occupations listed at the top in descending order.

I have asked both my professor and TA for help, and my TA pointed me toward the `arrange()` function and `desc(mydata[, input$first])`, but that only calls the first value in the related column, and not the actual column with that column name.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you! My code is below.

```
mydata <- iris
skillz <- names(mydata)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Weighted App"),

# Sidebar with little paragraph with inputs from person 
sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("nothing", "Hi, I am trying to get my app to work. Here are ome options" = c("GED", "Bachelor's Degree", "Master's Degree", "PhD", "Trade School Certification", "Other"), selectize = FALSE),
     selectInput("first", "I want to look at these 3 traits of irises 1:", choices = skillz, multiple = FALSE),
     selectInput("second", "2:", choices = skillz, multiple = FALSE),
     selectInput("third", "3:", choices = skillz, multiple = FALSE)
  ),
  # Show a table of the recommended occupations
  mainPanel(
     tableOutput("results")
     #verbatimTextOutput('values')
     #Professor:"Look at more examples on Shiny to see if you have an error. Think error in output here"

      )
   )
)


# Define server logic required to give weighted table
server <- function(input, output) {

       output$results <- reactive({
      # generate table based on inputs from the above 3 options
     filtered <- arrange(mydata, desc(mydata[,input$first]), desc(mydata[,input$second]), desc(mydata[,input$third])) 
     filtered

#If data table fails, maybe just print?   
#  output$values <- reactivePrint(
#   {
 #   list(x1 = input$first, x2 = input$second, x3 = input$third) 
  # } 
 #)

   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Again, I think my error is in my `arrange()` function,  but I'm not sure how to get it to actually call the column with my input name.

Edit: I tried using `deparse()` but that also just returns that there is "no column 'input$first'"...

```
skill1 <- deparse(input$first)
skill2 <- deparse(input$second)
skill3 <- deparse(input$third)
filtered <- arrange(mydata, desc(mydata[,skill1]), desc(mydata[,skill2]), desc(mydata[,skill3])) 
filtered
```

Edit 2: I have made the data more general. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `arrange` and other dplyr verbs use tidy evaluation semantics. This means that while using a variable which contains the name of the column, we need to convert the string to a symbol and then use `!!` while evaluating. A simple example below.

```
data(iris)
library(magrittr)

var1 <- "Species"
var2 <- "Sepal.Length"
var3 <- "Petal.Length"

iris %>% dplyr::arrange(dplyr::desc(!!rlang::sym(var1)),
                        dplyr::desc(!!rlang::sym(var2)), 
                        dplyr::desc(!!rlang::sym(var3)))
```

**EDIT 1:** Added solution to the reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Weighted App"),
# Sidebar with little paragraph with inputs from person 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("education", , label = "education", 
          choices = c("GED", "Bachelor's Degree", "Master's Degree", 
                      "PhD", "Trade School Certification", "Other"), 
          selectize = FALSE),
      selectInput("first", "I want to look at these 3 traits of irises 
                 1:", choices = skillz, multiple = FALSE),
      selectInput("second", "2:", choices = skillz, multiple = FALSE),
      selectInput("third", "3:", choices = skillz, multiple = FALSE)
), 
# Show a table of the recommended occupations
mainPanel(
   tableOutput("results")
  )
 )
)


#Define server logic required to give weighted table
server <- function(input, output) {

  mydata <- iris
  skillz <- names(mydata)

  #Use renderTable instead of reactive
   output$results <- renderTable({
       # Arranging the rows according to the selected variables
       filtered <- mydata %>% 
            dplyr::arrange(dplyr::desc(!!rlang::sym(input$first)),
                          dplyr::desc(!!rlang::sym(input$second)), 
                          dplyr::desc(!!rlang::sym(input$third))) 
       unselectedCols <-setdiff(colnames(filtered), 
                                         unique(c(input$first,
                                                 input$second,
                                                 input$third)))

       #Reordering columns according to the selections
       filtered <- filtered %>% 
                        dplyr::select(!!rlang::sym(input$first),
                                      !!rlang::sym(input$second),
                                      !!rlang::sym(input$third), 
                                      !!unselectedCols)
       filtered
    })
 }

 #Run the application 
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

- Using `sym` and `!!` operator on the variable containing the column name to pass to the arrange function
- I've added an extra couple of lines of code which will reorder the data frame using `dplyr::select` so that the columns show in the order of selection. Variables are passed similarly using `!!` and `sym`
- You can use `renderTable` directly to show a reactive table in the output, instead of using `reactive`. `renderTable` has a reactive context.

Comment: Yes! It orders the entries in ascending order, but a quick change can make it descending order. Thank you very much!